# Understanding ListView and Adapters

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Given the following code:

```
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, new ArrayList<CustomClass>());

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

/** assuming that we have an ArrayList named arrayList and it has some elements in it */

adapter.addAll(arrayList);
```

So when I do this everything works and the UI is perfectly fine .
My question is , does the ListView keep calling getView method as long as there's empty space on the screen?
And that's why we were able to add elements after setting up the adapter to the listview

I mean when we first created the Listview and set the adapter , the adapter was empty, so the list view keep calling getView method infinitely until it receive some data?

Comment: No, not at all, until we notify adapter [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: @KrishnaSharma does the adapter call this method implicitly? Because I didn't call anything but it still works as expected and the ListView was populated with views

Comment: Yes, adapter call getView method implicitly